# File.Exists Is Not Adding File Number to Existing File in Directory Before Saving

Tags: vb.net, save, file-exists

I'm trying to check if the file exists in the directory in which the application was saved and if so, to add a number at the end -1, -2. -3 - based on whether a file with the same name already exists. My code is below:

```
 Dim FileName, FilePath As String
 Dim FileNumber As Integer

 FileName = ProjectName 
 FilePath = Path.Combine(CurrentDirectory, FileName)

 If File.Exists(FilePath) = True Then
    Do While File.Exists(FilePath)
          FileNumber = FileNumber + 1
          FileName = FileName & "-" & FileNumber
          FilePath = Path.Combine(CurrentDirectory, FileName)
    Loop
  End If

  NewWorkbook.SaveAs(FilePath)
```

When I run this code and the file is saving the first time, it works as intended but if I try saving the file with the same name a second time, there is no iterated FileNumber added to it, so the file name stays the same and it cannot save without replacing the original file.

Why is the File.Exists not recognizing that this file already exists and how can I fix this?

Comment: There is an error in your code. You are missing the & in this line _FileName = FileName & "-" FileNumber_

Comment: However this logic is wrong from the start. What happens at the third iteration to your FileName variable with constantly re-adding to itself with the line above?

Comment: @Steve Thanks for catching that - I accidentally removed it when formatting the code in my question. Edited my answer to include that.

Comment: @Steve It's going to keep adding the new file number, yes - i can edit this code to fix that but I'm still going to be using the File.Exists(FilePath) and since it is not recognizing that the file exists for the first iteration, why is it not being recognized? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try hard coding the FilePath.

Comment: And how are you using this? In a button's click event?

Comment: @preciousbetine Yes, this is under a Button Click. And can you also explain what do you mean by hard-coding the file path? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a logical problem in your code. You continue to modify the same variable and building continuosly new names.
For example. Suppose to have initially a file with the name "Project.vb". At the first iteration inside the loop you check for a file named "Project.vb1", if your loop continues at the second iteration you check for a file named "Project.vb12" and so on.

A more correct way could be

```
Dim FileName, FileWithoutExtension, FileExtension, FilePath As String
Dim FileNumber As Integer = 1
Dim currentDirectory As String = "E:\temp" ' as an example
FileName = "test.txt"                      ' as an example

FileExtension = Path.GetExtension(FileName)
FileWithoutExtension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(FileName)
FilePath = Path.Combine(CurrentDirectory, FileName)

' No need of additional if to test file existance.
Do While File.Exists(FilePath)
    FileNumber = FileNumber + 1
    ' Rebuild the Filename part wtih all the info
    FileName = FileWithoutExtension & "-" & FileNumber.ToString("D3") + FileExtension
    FilePath = Path.Combine(CurrentDirectory, FileName)
Loop
NewWorkbook.SaveAs(FilePath)
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying why the error in the logic wouldn't work! I added your code and tried running that however, if I run the program again, once it is saving, an Excel error pops up with: _A file with the name (Original File Name without the added -1) already exists. Would you like to replace it?_

Comment: I have tried this code (without using Excel but just a File.WriteAllText and I have now many different files. I could only suggest you to use the debugger to check if the code is executing as expected and what values are present in the FilePath variable at the end of the loop

Comment: Thank you for the help Steve! From checking the variables, I realized that even now File.Exists(Filepath) returns a false value though the file exists.

Comment: Possibly a permission problem.

Comment: The `If` statement is superfluous as the `While` statement will serve the same purpose.  If the file does not exist, it won't enter the loop.